# CMake ignores "Treat warnings as errors" (/WX) when generating Windows projects

Tags: cmake

My CMake version is `3.18.0-rc2`. In my project's CMakeLists.txt I have the following lines which are supposed to crank up the warning levels and treat all warnings as errors:

```
if(MSVC)
    add_compile_options(/W4 /WX)
    add_link_options(/W4 /WX)
else()
    add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -Wl,--fatal-warnings)
endif()
```

I've only been able to test things out on Windows so far - the non-MSVC options are there for if/when we try to compile on other platforms in future.

When I generate Visual Studio projects with CMake and check the settings, the warning level is appropriately set to `/W4`, but `/WX` is not enabled - it is set to `/WX-` instead.

I know that `add_compile_options()` is having an effect because if I change the warning level to something else (`/W3`, for instance), I see this reflected in the project settings. However, it appears that no matter what I do, `/WX` is not respected. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. There may be something else in your project influencing the `/WX` setting, or your `add_compile_options` command is being set in the wrong scope to correctly update the target properties as you expect. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: You're right - there was something buried within a dependency of one of the projects that switched off `/WX`. Glad I'm not going completely mad, in that case.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asker clarified in the comments with the help of [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987854) that:

> there was something buried within a dependency of one of the projects that switched off `/WX`.

This kind of issue can be avoided when dependencies and other projects that require a minimum CMake version of CMake 3.24 use [the `COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR.html) and/or [the corresponding CMake defaulter variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR.html), which provides a cross-platform way to set this kind of property per target and default values for directory scopes.

To add to that, users can also globally disable `COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR` by using [the `--compile-no-warning-as-error` argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-compile-no-warning-as-error).